# Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick en HTML generado por InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, foreach, google-api

**Edito con el problema actual**: me salta el error Uncaught ReferenceError: guardarLibro is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (search.php:1) que supone mi archivo html. Sin embargo, la llamada a la función no se realiza en ese html sino que se realiza en una parte de código HTML generado por Javascript precisamente al hacer click en el botón de buscar. Adjunto el código en su situación actual:

**Ampliación:** Visual Studio Code me dice esto sobre la función que no aparece activa "'guardarLibro' is declared but its value is never read", lo cual quizás puede ser porque la llamada a la función está dentro de un document.getElementById("books").innerHTML, es decir, dentro de código html generado una vez apretado un botón anterior.

¿Cómo podría hacer para activar esta función?

```
$("#search_form").submit(function(e) {
$("#books").html("");

e.preventDefault();

function Libro(isbn, titulo, autor) {
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.titulo = titulo;
  this.autor = autor;
}

var cont = 0;
var arr = new Array();
var resultados = new Array();


var searchQuery = $("#search_txt").val();
searchQuery = searchQuery.split(" ").join("+");

var buscar = $("#search_txt").val();
if(buscar == "")
  {
    alert("Por favor, introduce algún término de búsqueda");
   }
   
   function guardarLibro(isbn){
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function(){

      $( "#add" ).replaceWith( "<i class='fas fa-check-circle' style='color=#02c39a;'></i>Añadido" );

      for (i = 0; i < resultados.length; i++) {
        if(miLibro[i].isbn==isbn){
          isbnL = miLibro[i].isbn;
          title = miLibro[i].title;
          author = miLibro[i].author;
        }
      }

      var url = 'guardarlibro.php';
      $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: "POST",
          data: {
             isbnL, title, author
             
          },
          success: function(response) {
              
          }
       });
  });
  }

$.ajax({
  url: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchQuery,
  success: function(json) {
    var htmlcontent = "";
    var thumb = "";
    var author = "";
    var isbnL="";
    var title="";
    arr = json.items;
    
    
    arr.forEach(function(dato) {
      if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.imageLinks != "undefined") {
        thumb = dato.volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail;
      } else {
        thumb = "http://i.imgur.com/oM3MdAi.png";
      }
      // AUTHOR
      if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.authors != "undefined") {
        author = dato.volumeInfo.authors[0];
      }
      
      if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.title != "undefined") {
        title = dato.volumeInfo.title[0];
      }
      
       if (typeof dato.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers != "undefined") {
        isbnL = dato.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[0].identifier;
      }

      var miLibro = new Libro(isbnL, title, author);
      resultados.push(miLibro);

      htmlcontent +=
        "<div class='cards'><div class='card-content'><div class='media'><div class='media-left'><figure class='image is-128x128'><img src='"+thumb+"' alt='alt text' /></figure></div><div class='media-content'><p class='title is-4'>"+
        dato.volumeInfo.title +"</p><p class='subtitle is-6'>"+author+"</p><button id='add' class='button is-primary add' onclick='guardarLibro("+isbnL+")'>Añadir a mi lista</button></div></div></div></div>";
      
        document.getElementById("books").innerHTML =
      "<div>" + htmlcontent + "</div><br>";
    }),
    document.getElementById("books").innerHTML =
      "<div>" + htmlcontent + "</div><br>";

    
  }
});
```

});

**Contexto anterior:** Estoy usando la Api de Google Books para hacer una búsqueda de libros y guardar los que me interesen a través de un botón a una biblioteca personal almacenada en una BBDD creada por mí a través de Php. El botón se genera automáticamente por DOM en cada iteración. Mi problema es que haga click en el resultado que sea, solo me guarda en la base de datos el último item de la iteración. Antes lo tenía hecho con un for y pasé a hacerlo con un ForEach para evitar esto, pero sigue sucediendo lo mismo y ya no sé cómo abarcarlo.

Mi javascript: (lo elimino para no saturar el post ya que el actual está ya arriba)

Comment: Por supuesto que solo se te guardan los de la última iteración. Eso es porque en cada iteración estás reemplazando el contenido de las tres variables (author, title e isbn) por el valor del libro de esa iteración, así que cuando acabas el forEach, lo que tienes ahí almacenado es literalmente el valor del último libro! Necesitas, primero que nada, almacenar TODOS los valores recibidos de TODOS los libros en algún array/objeto, y luego en la función del botón, indicarle qué libro en concreto quieres guardar (por ejemplo, usando el índice del libro en tu array de libros)

Comment: Tiene mucho sentido, ¡gracias! He creado un array para guardar los objetos y ahora en cada iteración creo un objeto mi Libro y hago un push al array. Lo que no se me ocurre es cómo relacionar a cuál de los resultados se hace click en la función add. Por si ayuda, así es como sale en la interfaz https://imgur.com/a/vQylwEy

Comment: Primero, extrae la función que pones al click de los botones `.add` a una función con nombre -> `function guardarLibro(isbn){/*código de la función aquí*/}`, entonces podrás, dentro del forEach, añadir la función a tu botón de la siguiente manera: `<button id='add' class='button is-primary add' onClick='guardarLibro(' + 
isbn +')'>Añadir a mi lista</button>`, entonces podrás filtrar tus libros buscando el que tenga el isbn que coincide, y ya podrás guardarlo! Espero que te sirva

Comment: Yo creo que la función estaría bien, el problema es que me da un error desde el html porque dice que la función guardarlibro no está definida en HTMLButtonElement.onclick. Pero claro, esto se crea desde el JavaScript, no en el archivo html. Por cierto, este archivo realmente es un php porque lleva variables de sesión, ¿quizas por eso no la coge?

Comment: No creo, ese error suele darse cuando intentas añadir una función al evento click antes de que exista la entidad. Por cierto, el evento que debes bindear es `onclick` todo en minúsculas, tal vez eso pueda ser el error? Siempre puedes editar la pregunta para reflejar tu duda actual, seguro que alguien será capaz de ayudarte!

Comment: La verdad es que tenía la C de onclick en mayúscula, sí! De todas formas, sigue persistiendo el error. Y gracias también por el consejo, la verdad que no manejo esto y ni siquiera sé formatear código a la hora de postear una respuesta jajaja La verdad es que he probado poner la función antes del bucle, dentro del ajax pero fuera del bucle... pero con todas sigue persistiendo el Uncaught ReferenceError: guardarLibro is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (search.php:1)

Comment: Has probado a mover la definición de `function guardarLibro(...` a antes de usarla??

Comment: Sí!! Precisamente acabo de actualizar el post con el código tal y como lo tengo ahora, puedes ver que está después de declarar las variables y antes del ajax que incluye el foreach.

Comment: Guardarlibro.php no es una url valida para hacer una llamada ajax... eso, no es una url. Si vas a hacer una llamada a un servidor, debes decirle la url a la cual llamar

Comment: @gbianchi ahora mismo esto se trata de un proyecto local por lo que guardarlibro.php es la dirección del directorio. Sé que eso funciona porque es el archivo que se encarga de guardar los datos en la base de datos y eso lo hace, por lo tanto entra en ajax. No debería haberle puesto el mismo nombre a la función que a un documento php porque veo ahora que puede suponer confusión, pero la funcion guardarLibro() que es la que da error y guardarlibro.php son cosas distintas.